# Kernel Panic on Debian Buster with 128 MB of memory

Tags: debian, kernel-panic

When running Debian Buster 10 with 128 MB of memory get a Kernel Panic.  However it works fine on 256 MB of memory. The output lines are:

```
? initrd_load+Ox5e/Ox5e 
ksys_write+Ox57/0xdO 
write+Ox29/0x5a 
do_copy+Ox9b/Oxc8 
write_buffer+Ox27/0x37 
flush_buffer+Ox34/0x8b 
__gunzip+Ox26e/0x315 
? bunzip2+0x397/0x397 
? initrd_load+Ox5e/Ox5e 
? __gunzip+Ox315/0x315 
gunzip+Oxe/Ox11 
? initrd_load+Ox5e/Ox5e 
unpack_to_rootfs+0x182/0x2c6 
? initrd_load+Ox5e/Ox5e 
? unpack_to_rootfs+0x2c6/0x2c6 
? do_early_param+0x8e/Ox8e 
populate_rootfs+0x59/0x10b 
do_one_initca11+0x46/0x1c3 
? do_early_param+0x8e/Ox8e 
kernel_init_freeable+Ox189/0x218 
? rest_init+Oxaa/Oxaa 
kernel_init+Oxa/Oxl0d 
ret_from_fork+Ox35/0x40
```

Comment: When exactly are you getting this message? At boot? It looks like `initrd` ran out of room to decompress its image into RAM. How is your system set up?

Answer (score 4):

The kernel is unable to decompress its initramfs, which it needs to boot in Debian’s default configuration.

The documented minimum amount of memory for Debian 10 on x86 [is 256 MiB](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/ch03s04.en.html).

Comment: Thank you.  I was relying on the part of the documentation that said "The actual minimum memory requirements are a lot less than the numbers listed in this table." There used to be a time when you can start Ubuntu with 96 MB.  The system does not even use 128 MB after startup. But I suppose that's what it takes today for a Debian system to boot up today. Appreciate the answer.

Comment: Right, but I suspect “a lot less” doesn’t extend as far as “half”. The actual requirements vary depending on the size of the initramfs, so you could try reducing that — look at `/etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf`, in particular the `MODULES` setting. To take things further, you could build your own kernel with all the drivers required to mount the root file system built-in, then boot without an initramfs at all.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I removed 4 of the 7 mount points and it still did not matter and ended with kernel panic.  I do have the answer I needed that there is nothing funny about my install that is causing the issue.  Happy to allocate the required memory.